# Reference to type 'System.IConvertible' claims it is defined in assembly mscorlib

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

Anytime I try to reference an `NUNIT` data type in the iOS framework, I am given a compiler error saying it can't find the `IConvertible` type

> Error CS7069: Reference to type `System.IConvertible' claims it is defined assembly`mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', but it could not be found (CS7069) (logic)

I was able to reproduce this by creating a brand new Xamarin.Forms project that only targets iOS.

[image]

Immediately after creating it, I added a second Xamarin.Forms project, this time a PCL.

[image]

I then needed to add the Xamarin.iOS library so that I can reference the iOS specific APIs, specifically the Photos API. I did this by navigating to

> ~/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.0.1.29/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll

Lastly, I added a blank class to the new PCL project, and created a locally scoped NUNIT field. This is where the compiler error happens. This happens in my current project when I try to get the number of photos in a `PHAssetCollection`, as that is an NUNIT data type.

```
using System;

namespace logic
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
        public EmptyClass()
        {
            nuint test = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the compiler error I've referenced above. How can I solve this? This has become a blocking issue for me, am I referencing the wrong Xamarin.iOS.dll? It's not available in the list of nuget packages when I scan for them, so I can't add it via NuGet. NuGet only has Xamarin.Forms.dll available.

### Update 1

After trying a few different combinations, I think that I have a working solution. Instead of creating a Xamarin.Forms Library, I created a normal iOS PCL library instead. This solved that problem.

I don't know why the Xamarin.Forms library wouldn't work. Is it not intended to be used for platform specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms PCL's need to be platform agnostic. If you have a NUnit project that needs access to a Xamarin.iOS specific reference, then you need to build within the iOS project / iOS PCL.

Xamarin.iOS.dll can only be referenced from a iOS related project.